# Eclipse Pydev tooltip shortcut

Tags: eclipse, pydev, shortcut

I've struggling to configure a keyboard shortcut for showing the 'Show toolkit Description' that shows the error or info on some object.  I can get the popup by hovering over the object like this:

[image]

It seems to be some issue with pydev configurations because a shortcut (F2)  works when editing C/C++ files.

I checked the General->Keys and there is a shortcut assigned for general text editing using F2 but it still doesnt work:
[image]

Currently F2 for py files is configured to send the selected text to the console and it works:
[image]

So I tried assigned a different shortcut for pydev for the tooltip command but still nothing:
[image]

I tried with the latest version of pydev plugin 3.9 and an older 2.8 and I haven't manage to make it work.

Any ideas?